# While Loop switch statement till statement is false

Tags: c#

I have created two classes which use the same property. The direction class which the function GenerateRamdon which is inherited from the second class know as health. The issue which I am finding is that when it goes to run the code in the GenerateRamdon function it is not reaching the switch statement. On review the breakpoints and the information which is being passed, the Ramdom method is working fine and is generate the correct Number and when the while loop is deleted it is going to the correct if statement.

```
private void GenerateRamdon()
{
    while (StartHealth < 0)
    {
        Random DirectionRandon = new Random();
        int GetDirect = DirectionRandon.Next(0, 100);

        if (GetDirect <= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move straight, Right or Left");
            string FirstDirect = Console.ReadLine();

            while (FirstDirect.Equals(true))
            {
                switch (FirstDirect)
                {
                    case "Straight":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk straight forward");
                        break;

                    case "Right":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your right");
                        break;

                    case "Left":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your left");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Vailid direction");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (GetDirect > 21 && GetDirect <= 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move stay, back or Left");
            string SecontDirect = Console.ReadLine();

            while (SecontDirect.Equals(true))
            {
                switch (SecontDirect)
                {
                    case "Stay":
                        Console.WriteLine("You stand still");
                        break;

                    case "Back":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk back to where you came but it looks all different");
                        break;

                    case "Left":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your left");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Vailid direction");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (GetDirect > 21 && GetDirect <= 60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move Back, Right or Left");
            string ThridDirect = Console.ReadLine();

            while (ThridDirect.Equals(true))
            {
                switch (ThridDirect)
                {
                    case "Back":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk back to where you came but it looks all different");
                        break;

                    case "Right":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your right");
                        break;

                    case "Left":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your left");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Vailid direction");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (GetDirect > 61 && GetDirect <= 80)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move back, straight or Right");
            string FourthDirect = Console.ReadLine();

            while (FourthDirect.Equals(true))
            {
                switch (FourthDirect)
                {
                    case "Back":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk back to where you came but it looks all different");
                        break;

                    case "Straight":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk straight forward");
                        break;

                    case "Right":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your right");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Vailid direction");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move straight, Right, Stay or Left");
            string FifthDirect = Console.ReadLine();

            while (FifthDirect.Equals(true))
            {
                switch (FifthDirect)
                {
                    case "Straight":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk straight forward");
                        break;

                    case "Right":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your right");
                        break;

                    case "Stay":
                        Console.WriteLine("You stand still");
                        break;

                    case "Left":
                        Console.WriteLine("You walk to your left");
                        break;

                    default:
                       Console.WriteLine("Please enter Vailid direction");
                       break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second class which is under health has this function which holds the information for the starting health of the character and I want the directions to keep looping through till the user life(HP) hit's zero.

```
private void StartHP()
{
    this.StartHealth = 100;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(y,x);
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("HP: " + StartHealth);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

When I go to loop through the switch statement the code is not being accessed and the console application is closing. I was just wondering why this is and guidance on how to fix the issue. Thanks for any information which you can provide.

Comment: Well, first of all `FirstDirect.Equals(true)` will _always_ be false.

Comment: `string.Equals(bool)` will always be false.

Comment: Did you mean to write while(true)? Please don't do this in practice though, you want your loops to terminate

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your issues: Please do move the `new Random();` out of the loop. Any loop. Always. Make it static.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here; let's start with making sure our request for input is inside the loop, and we have a boolean (true/false) to store whether the program is happy with the input:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to move straight, Right or Left");
bool isInputValid = false; // stores the validity of the input, reusable
string FirstDirect = "moonwalk"; // this will be overwritten inside of the loop
while (!isValidInput) // same as: while (isValidInput == false)
{
  firstDirect = Console.ReadLine();
  switch (FirstDirect)
  {
    case "Straight":
      Console.WriteLine("You walk straight forward");
      isValidInput = true;
      break;
    case "Right":
      Console.WriteLine("You walk to your right");
      isValidInput = true;
      break;
    case "Left":
      Console.WriteLine("You walk to your left");
      isValidInput = true;
      break;
    default:
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter Valid direction");
      isValidInput = false; // not necessary, but there you go
      break;
    }
  }
}
isValidInput = false; // reset for next loop
```

We can actually reuse the directional indicator (`firstDirect` which I would change to `inputDirection`) variable in the subsequent loops unless you want to hold onto the data to know what their previous choices were.